# Database of Software

Tags: database

I'm looking for a database of commonly installed Windows software. At minimum I need the name of the software and the executable name, but it'd also be nice to have the publisher and the common installation path, etc. Basically, I'd like to be able to query it to find all the software by Adobe and the associated executable name, etc.

Basically I'm looking to be able to do

```
SELECT * FROM Software WHERE Publisher = 'Microsoft' 
SELECT * FROM Software WHERE Executable = 'devenv.com'
```

I came across an effort to create such a database a long time ago, but can't seem to find it now. Maybe it fizzled out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this programming related?  If so, you should note the intended use of this database in your question, to prevent downvotes.

Comment: What would you want to use this database for?

Comment: The question is too vague.  What platform are you talking about?  Are you just looking for the URL of the effort you are referring to or are you hoping someone has a database sitting around that they are willing to publish?  Also, it doesn't seem to be a programming question the way it's phrased.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: He wants a list of Windows program.

Comment: Basically I'm looking to be able to do SELECT * FROM Software WHERE Publisher = 'Microsoft' or SELECT * FROM Software WHERE Executable = 'devenv.com'. Not sure how much more specific I can be.

Comment: Can someone reopen this?

Comment: I've reopened it.  I'd expect it to get closed again if you don't clarify in what way this is a programming-related question.

Comment: You want us to create a database of software for you in 1 sentence?

Comment: No, I'm asking if anyone knows of anything that exists. I've come across something years ago, but can't seem to find it again. I understand it's not directly a programming question, but I think it's a little more related than "What’s your favorite 'programmer' cartoon?"

Comment: @Daok, no, he wants to know if there exists a database that someone has already made.

Comment: I remember there being some kind of open-source style initiative to catalog all software. I didn't realize this question was going to cause such a stir. I was thinking about how nice it would be to find it again last week and haven't been able to come up with anything, hence the question.

Comment: +0. (I don't yet have enough reputation to downvote your question.) Why did you want such a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, someone asked a question on reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/7civs/ask_prog_where_can_i_find_lists_of_data_in_useful/) that contained the original website I was looking for.

Anyone looking for a database of general information (including the database of software I was looking for) can find it at http://www.freebase.com/.

There were also a couple other interesting open databases at http://infochimps.org/, http://theinfo.org/ and http://www.datawrangling.com/some-datasets-available-on-the-web

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet would be to [query](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3079381) amazon.com, since they sell lots of software and provide public interfaces to access their database.

Answer (score 1):

Secunia, the security company, has a tool called [Secunia PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/) that attempts to list all the software on a Windows computer and checks it against a database of known vulnerabilities, so you can keep your stuff up to date.  This might have some overlap with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's also looking, try [wikidata.org](https://wikidata.org) - they have a fantastic [online query editor](https://query.wikidata.org) you can use to probe around the data set.

A quick query for a list of 13155 pieces of software along with the related programming language and operating system (with a lot of gaps and duplicates unfortunately, but still very workable):

```
SELECT ?monarch ?monarchLabel ?programming_language ?programming_languageLabel ?operating_system ?operating_systemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  { ?monarch wdt:P31 wd:Q7397. } UNION { ?monarch wdt:P31 wd:Q40056. }
  OPTIONAL { ?monarch wdt:P277 ?programming_language. }
  OPTIONAL { ?monarch wdt:P306 ?operating_system. }
}
```

Depending on what you're looking for you might want to include websites or other categories by adding more union cases, or add more properties (the query editor has great suggestions like *developer*, *license* and *use*).

Answer (score 0):

You can do some **screen scraping** with some website that contain **list of software** and build yourself a database of all software and publisher.

Here is some website that contain some list of software:

- http://www.digital-digest.com/software/index.php
- http://www.bestshareware.net/allsoftware-w.htm

Answer (score 0):

here is the list of applications compatible with windows vista.

there is a excel sheet out there at microsoft, you can find more software products.

http://www.iexbeta.com/wiki/index.php/Windows_Vista_Software_Compatibility_List

hope this helps